# Android Chrome deeplink when coming from other application

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking

I'm having some trouble to open my custom app from chrome browser on Android.
I read a lot of questions about this but couldn't find an answer.

The deep link to my application works fine when everything is handled in the browser.
What I implemented is a payment page. In my app I open a web browser where the user can pay. When the user finishes his payment I call an URL like "myScheme://payment_accepted". This works fine.

The problem is when the user tries to pay via a banking application. My application opens the browser to my pay page. One of the payment methods is to pay via banking app. Once the user payed with the banking app, the banking app opens my "myScheme://payment_accepted" URL in chrome browser but chrome shows "This webpage is not available". (like following picture: http://s16.postimg.org/xuzqn5iv9/Screenshot_2015_02_17_20_37_53.png)

Is there something special to do?

Here is my code in my manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.PaymentResultActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeWhite"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myScheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**EDIT:**
I see the URL in the topbar of chrome but it doesn't start my application.

Comment: What happens when you test your App through the `adb shell`? Using the info on the [Android Deep Linking page](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#testing-filters).

Comment: I'll try that right now and let you know

Comment: @Tigger When I execute the command, I get to the payment confirmation page. So that works.

Comment: Usually the first time the option to open a link with another App happens, there is a confirmation box with possible options. Is it possible that you have "set" the default option for opening that kind of link before to the browser?

Comment: The thing is that when I execute a payment in the browser I come back to the app, but when I execute it via the banking app, it doesn't work. So I don't think it's a problem with the default app to handle the request

Comment: Can you paste the code how you invoke the payment confirmation link after the payment has been made by a different banking app.

Comment: Well my guess is that there is something wrong over there, but I have no access to that. I want to make sure that my implementation is correct, that I'm not forgetting something.